# Обфускация кода на c#

Tags: c#, обфускация

Может кто подскажет проект для обфускации кода на c#. Интересует обфускация именно кода, а не экзешника (наподобии Net Reflector). Нужна обфускация такого же плана как и для JavaScrypt.

Comment: Наймите неопытного разработчика. Он напишет такой код, что разобраться с ним будет сложнее, чем с обфусцированным кодом. Потери в производительности примерно одинаковые.

Comment: Можно обфусцировать exe-файл, а затем воспользоваться любым конвертером обратно в C# (скажем, DotPeek). Возможно, придётся поправить пару мелочей, но так-то должно сработать.

Comment: Это называется не обфускация, а минификация.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C# Source Code Obfuscator](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscator.html)

[Eazfuscator](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net)

[AppFuscator](http://appfuscator.com/)

[Obfuscar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/obfuscar/)

Есть еще такая статья вот, про [обфускацию](https://habrahabr.ru/post/74463/). В целом там обзор методик обфускации.

И еще [статья](http://evilcoderr.blogspot.ru/2013/01/vs2010.html) обзорная по обфускаторам.

Но если речь идет только об обфускации исходного кода, то должно бы хватить C# Source Code Obfuscator.