# Записать и прочитать dll как массив байт

Tags: c#, byte

Есть dll которая нормально работает. Перевожу её в массив байт вот так :

```
        byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string name = "Dll.mvvm";
        foreach (byte byt in b)
        {
        File.AppendAllText(name, byt.ToString());
        }
```

затем пытаюсь этот массив динамически подгрузить как сборку  и использовать:

```
        byte[] massDll = File.ReadAllBytes(pathTodll);
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(massDll);
        object o = a.CreateInstance("namespace.Class");
        Type t = a.GetType("namespace.Class");
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Start");
        mi.Invoke(o,null);
```

Ошибка :

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "80495 bytes loaded from ReadWriteAllBytes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Получившийся файл массива байтов почти в 2 раза больше исходной dll. В чем может быть проблема? Имеет ли значение в каком расширении я сохраняю массив байт ?

Comment: а зачем вы делаете `byt.ToString()` при записи в файл? Естественно при таком преобразовании размер получается в 2-3 раза больше. А читаете после этого не строки, а снова байты, и что должен по вашему сделать лоадер с полученной кашей?

Comment: @rdorn вы правы. и вместо `AppendAllText` нужно было `WriteAllBytes`.  Исходной целью было закодировать dll что бы по возможности скрыть исходный код. Поэтому и пытался привести к строке.

Comment: Не скроете вы исходный код в .NET. Можете создать некоторые проблемы для декомпиляторов, не более. Тут уже не раз обсуждались обфускаторы и попытки скрыть код, поищите по сайту, это себя не окупает.

Comment: Можно было просто `File.Copy(...)` с указанием нужных имен

Comment: a нельзя ли зашифровать массив байт и уже расшифрованный использовать как dll ?

Comment: Так в принципе можно. Сначала читаете байты - шифруете - пишете байты. Потом читаете байты, расшифровываете, загружаете

Comment: только учтите, что это не слишком задержит желающих залезть внутрь. Ключ для дешифровки вам придется хранить где-то в приложении, которое будет загружать зашифрованные сборки, а значит его можно извлечь и расшифровать все что нужно

Comment: А код, который занимается шифрованием/расшифровкой тоже зашифровать?

Comment: а как зашифровать байты?

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/337738/198316 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584567/198316 Можно еще накопать по метке [обфускация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%84%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Возьмите какой-нибудь крипто-провайдер, для начала можно родной .NET-овский. Документация по нему имеется.